# python mysql syntax for limit as available no. of rows

Tags: python, mysql

I know little internet knowledge about python in mysql,is there any syntax to make the limit by default as the number of available rows in a table by providing any new things?

```
"select * from ques LIMIT 100"
```

this is done normally,what in case if user doesnot know the no. of all the rows and he needs till the last row?is there any syntax?answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting all rows? Remove the limit thingy...

```
select * from ques
```

Comment: If this helps you, please accept it! Just tick the button on the left.